# How to check if a sequence exists in my schema?

Tags: sql, oracle11g, sequences

Is there a way to retrieve all the sequences defined in an existing oracle-sql db schema?

Ideally I would like to use something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM all_sequences WHERE owner = 'me';
```

which apparently doesn't work.

Comment: What are you looking for exactly and what does your table look like?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT object_name
  FROM all_objects
 WHERE object_type = 'SEQUENCE' AND owner = '<schema name>'
```

Answer (score 7):

Yes:

```
select * from user_sequences;
```

Your SQL was almost correct too:

```
select * from all_sequences where sequence_owner = user;
```

Comment: Thanks Tony, this works as well, but I chose the other answer as it is more generic.

Answer (score 3):

Below query can be triggered in Oracle Developer to check whether sequence present in DB or not :

```
SELECT count(*) count FROM user_sequences WHERE sequence_name = 'SEQ_NAME';
```

If '`SEQ_NAME`' present in your DB then count will return 1 else 0 .